# php rtu modbus connection write to coil and read holding registers

Tags: php, microcontroller, modbus, modbus-tcp

First of all this is my first attempt for PHP - Modbus.
I am trying to read registers from a modbus register using phpmodbus from http://code.google.com/p/phpmodbus/

My micro-controller is connected to serial port COM10 by Prolific usb-to-serial common port.

I have run this in modscan its working fine. I want to read/write data to registers.

I am not able to communicate through php. Can someone help?

here is what i have tried

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Phpmodbus/ModbusMaster.php';

// Create Modbus object
$ip = "192.192.15.51";
$modbus = new ModbusMaster($ip, "UDP");

try {
    // FC 3
    $moduleId = 0;
    $reference = 12288;
    $mw0address = 12288;
    $quantity = 6;
    $recData = $modbus->readMultipleRegisters($moduleId, $reference, $quantity);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $modbus;
    echo $e;
    exit;
}

?>
```

I am not sure which ip address should be given.

Answer (score 1):

From PhpModbus documentation: "Implementation of the basic functionality of the Modbus TCP and UDP based protocol using PHP".

It is not possible to scan a device connected to your serial port. One option would be to use a Modbus RTU/TCP gateway. PhpModbus would then connect via TCP to the gateway which is able to scan your serial device.

Comment: Is there any other library?

Comment: I've never worked with PhpModbus. The info I gave you is from the project's documentation. PhpModbus will only communicate via TCP or UDP.